# ADFS error: Failed to register SSL bindings for Device Registration Service: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, adfs

I'm running Windows Server 2016 Active Passive ADFS server, the primary ADFS server **ADFS01-VM** has been set up fine using the steps in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/install-the-ad-fs-role-service

The SSL SAN certificate *.domain.com has been imported with no issue on the primary server.

However, moving on to the secondary server called ADFS02-VM the error showing like below:
[image]

I have also executed the steps described in: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-support-for-alternate-hostname-binding-for-certificate-authentication

Under the Primary DFS server **ADFS01-VM**

```
Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding -Member ADFS02-VM.DOMAIN.com -Thumbprint 'B6DA73B83A759DEE37F975668266FE92B4E5F788'
```

This is the error message:

```
Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding : 
PS0317: One or more of AD FS servers returned errors during execution of command 'Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding'. 
Error information: 
PS0316: AD FS Server: 'localhost', Error: 'The specified SSL certificate with thumbprint 'B6DA73B83A759DEE37F975668266FE92B4E5F788' does not meet the requirements for configuring alternate Tls Client binding. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=613586.'.
PS0316: AD FS Server: 'ADFS02-VM.DOMAIN.com', Error: 'The specified SSL certificate with thumbprint 'B6DA73B83A759DEE37F975668266FE92B4E5F788' does not meet the requirements for configuring alternate Tls Client binding. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=613586.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding -Member ADFS02-VM.DOMAIN.com -Th ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AdfsAlternateTlsClientBinding], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.SetAlternateTlsClientBinding
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.